# Python (blpapi) _ Bloomberg API _ take Screenshot

Tags: python, api, screenshot, bloomberg, blpapi

I am trying to retrieve (automate) a price + a screenshot of the given price out of Bloomberg. I use Bloomberg Desktop in combination with the API (programming in Python).

I already read the documentation available on the official site and all the threads I could find but documentation overall seems limited.

I can retrieve the price of the security I want with :

```
from xbbg import blp
import blpapi

[...]

blp.bdp("MYSECURITY", ["PX_LAST"])
```

And I can't find a way to have the screenshot of the page. Manually I would do :
Search bar -> MYSECURITY   -> "Take Window Screenshot" -> "View Screen as Image"

I see 2 ways of doing it : the best way would be a direct function / query. The other way would be to "physically" open the DES page with python commands to the API and asking python to take a screenshot of the given screen with another library.

Hope someone can help,

Best Regards,

Comment: Experience suggests you will need to go the 2nd way. You can use `pywin32` to (i) find the Terminal window, (ii) send keystrokes to enter the ticker <yellow key> DES <Enter>, (iii) Send the Ctrl-C keystrokes, (iv) either write you own code to get the image off the clipboard (typically as a bitmap), use a python clipboard package, or (what I would probably do), open Word via COM and Paste Special, then save the image from there in whatever graphics format suits. Experience also teaches this is a world of frustration, and the end result is a flaky process.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply it looks ok to me. I guess if I take the screenshot just before requesting the price there should not be any discrepancy. In my case it is not a big deal if the user has to manually copy-paste into an excel file a picture afterwards. The goal is to prevent manual mistakes for individual pricings and keep audit proof for each request parametered manually more than launching 100 requests + pictures. The terminal being by default open should do it for (i) however how would you give it any commands ? Again I don't see documentation about it

Comment: If you Ctrl-C on the HP screen (for example) the screen goes to the clipboard in both text and picture versions. So you could kill two birds with one stone and get the price and the screenshot at the same time: you can paste special the picture, but also extract the text from the clipboard and parse it.